# How to run a service from a class?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a class like this :

`public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {`

I want to run a service from this class. But as I know, services can only be run from `Activitys` . So what is the solution?

How can I start a service and control it from another class?

Answer (score 1):

> > But as I know, services can only be runned from Activitys

That's not true. In order to run the service you just need a context, that is usually a reference to your activity.

So, inside ExpandableListAdapter you just make sure that the constructor receives an instance of your activity:

```
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

// somewhere else
mContext.startService(theIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most adapters have a context so you can make a call to getContext() which will give you a context back. This adapter does not have a context so you should have a custom constructor that takes a context and calls its super. Using the context you passed in you can call [startService(Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) just like you would in an activity.

Comment: `BaseExpandableListAdapter` does not have `getContex` method.

Comment: I edited my answer after I had thought of that. You can pass in a context in the constructor like you would for most adapters and just store it as a global variable.